Error while using matplotlib: "AttributeError: module 'gi' has no attribute 'require_version'"
I'm on Fedora 41, with a virtualenv with Python 3.12.7 (matplotlib==3.9.2). The following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

or just
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "4.0")

produce the error "AttributeError: module 'gi' has no attribute 'require_version'".
When I try to install PyGObject with pip, I get the following error:
$ pip install PyGObject
  ...
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [48 lines of output]

      ...
      Compiler for C supports arguments -fvisibility=hidden: YES
      Found pkg-config: YES (/usr/bin/pkg-config) 2.3.0
      Run-time dependency cairo found: YES 1.18.0
      Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried pkgconfig, pkgconfig and sysconfig)
      
      ../cairo/meson.build:51:15: ERROR: Python dependency not found

same error with pip install cairo
I tried MANY solutions given by some similar posts:
$ pkg-config --modversion gtk4
4.16.5

$ pip uninstall gi
WARNING: Skipping gi as it is not installed.

$ pip install PyGTK
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      ********************************************************************
      * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
      * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
      ********************************************************************
      [end of output]

$ sudo dnf install python3-gi
Updating and loading repositories:
Repositories loaded.
Failed to resolve the transaction:
No match for argument: python3-gi

$ sudo dnf install python3-gobject
Updating and loading repositories:
Repositories loaded.
The package 'python3-gobject-3.48.2-3.fc41.x86_64' is already installed.

same for python3-gobject-base and gobject-introspection.

I was able to fix the problem by running pip install --upgrade pygobject.
I found the solution in this GitHub issue, which received the following reply:

It seems that the error message is related to the version of the Gtk module. the 'gi' module is not the version required by the Stable Diffusion WebUI , the version of Gtk that is being used is not compatible with the version of Matplotlib that is installed.. You could try running this command in your terminal :
" pip install --upgrade pygobject "
This command will upgrade the 'pygobject' module, which contains the 'gi' module .


Thank you for the answer, but I trying with --upgrade give me the same result as the original post : ../cairo/meson.build:51:15: ERROR: Python dependency not found (see above).

So you can just try to install the necessary dependency: pip install pygobject
